# yeoman add twitter bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman

I am trying to use Yeoman for the first time.
And I want to use Bootstrap for CSS styling.
I've added it to the dependencies and I've npm installed it. It exist it node_modules.

Now I wonder if there is a smart way to require or include it to my project, or should I just go into index.html and reference it from modules?

*index.js*

```
var angular = require('angular');

var test = require('./app/controllers/main');
require('angular-ui-router');
var routesConfig = require('./routes');

require('./index.scss');

var app = 'app';
module.exports = app;

angular
  .module(app, ['ui.router'])
  .config(routesConfig)
  .component('app', test);
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Crossfit</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://fountainjs.io/assets/imgs/fountain.png" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman is a scaffolding tool used for webApps' creation : meaning it helps you with the creation of the basic skeleton (libs,code architecture and file organization ).
As for dependencies use inside your project, you need to implement it manually and according to your needs.
Since it's not a repetitive task, you don't need to automate it.

Comment: So to understand it, I would have to add it manually through my HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: you are welcome , I actually searched a while ago on the matter of automated integration of dependecies and I found that it was nearly impossible to predict where to integrate the libraries into html files if we don't have that information.